# Warninge message: In if (n >= 10000L) return(TRUE) : the condition has length > 1 out of nowhere

Tags: r

I have a large dofile which runs fine. However, suddenly i recieve the following Warning message:

```
Warning message:
In if (n >= 10000L) return(TRUE) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

This happens after the following line which shouldn't do anything:

```
##### Regression inklusive Yield_Amount und Distance_Closest_Port
```

After it occured the first time, it pops up whenever I run one or multiple lines of codes and it always pops up after the first line of code. It also shows up if i only run a simple # as code.
After a while it buildes up and shows

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (n >= 10000L) return(TRUE) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (n >= 10000L) return(TRUE) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I have looked up the meaning of this error code and how [it can be fixed](https://community.rstudio.com/t/the-condition-has-length-1-and-only-the-first-element-will-be-used/16737) but i don't have a single line of code that includes the if-command and I also don't have a variable that has the value of 10000 or the unit L. So, i was just wandering if this is a bug since it doesn't seem to effect any results or the code running.

I could provid my do-file and the data, but it is a very large dataset and a do-file with several hundred lines of code so i don't know how helpful this would be.

Comment: Are you using RStudio (or another IDE)? Occasionally warnings like this that keep popping up in different contexts are actually due to an issue with an IDE feature (such as autocomplete or linting).

Comment: I am using RStudio Version 2023.06.0 for Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The error `the condition has length > 1` is raised when your inequality is not of length one. For example in `if (n >= 10000)` you would expect `n` to be of length one. If `n` is a longer vector, above mentioned error is raised.

Example:

```
n <- 4
if (n > 1) print("works")
n <- 1:3
if (n > 1) print("does not work")
```

Without any other information/your code it's however difficult to say where the error comes from.